# LSZ theorem for photons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics, s-matrix-theory

Is there any discussion on what the [LSZ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula) for photons looks like? I would rather like a discussion of this in axial gauge $A_0 = 0$ (instead of the usual Lorenz gauge), but anything would do.

Comment: This seems to be asking for a commentary. Is there something specific you want to know?

Comment: This is a reference request I guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LSZ reduction for photons is discussed e.g. in (little) Chapter 56 of Srednicki's book

> http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007qft..book.....S

Comment: There is a draft (and errata) available for free download at the authors homepage: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html